# Can I style FullCalendar Timeslot LABELS?

Tags: css, fullcalendar

We're trying to group the hours of the day as "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening". Is it possible to add classes to any of the elements of the TR that would accomplish this?  I've played around with the CSS and styles with no luck at all.

In this example, we'd select Yellow for any times before noon.  Being the row for 7:00AM, we would like the Timeslot *label* saying "7am" to have a yellow background color based on the hour of the day being before noon.

```
<tr data-time="07:00:00">
    <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 36px;">  
        <span>7am</span>
    </td>
    <td class="fc-widget-content">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea. You can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
      $('.fc-axis.fc-time').each(function() {
        $(this).addClass(getClass($(this).parent().data('time')));
      })
    }
  });

  function getClass(timePart) {
    var hour = parseInt(moment("2016-12-20T" + timePart).format("H"));
    if (hour >= 6 && hour < 9) {
      return "morning";
    } else if (hour >= 9 && hour < 20) {
      return "day";
    } else {
      return "evening";
    }
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stzr6ddt/)